# Finding -1 to irrational powers

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification

I've been curious about $A=(-1)^r$ when $r$ takes different values. I know that if $r$ was an even number, $A$ will become $1$ and if it was odd, it will become $-1$. Now I want to know what will $A$ be if $r$ were an irrational number like $\sqrt{2}$.
Here's what i have done: According to Euler's identity we have $e^{\pi i}=-1$ and so $e^{\pi i\sqrt{2}}=(-1)^\sqrt{2}$ and $e^{i(\sqrt{2}\pi)}=(-1)^\sqrt{2}$. We also know that $e^{i\theta}=\sin\theta+i\cos{\theta}$. According to what i just showed, $(-1)^\sqrt{2}=e^{i(\sqrt{2}\pi)}=\sin{\pi\sqrt{2}}+i\cos{\pi\sqrt{2}}$ and from this we can find the exact value of $(-1)^\sqrt{2}$. Is what I have done correct? Is $(-1)^\sqrt{2}$ even a number?

Comment: What you did is sorta correct, but it isn't the whole story. You see $-1=e^{(2n+1)\pi i}$ for any integer $n$. So all the complex numbers $$e^{\sqrt2(2n+1)\pi i}$$ have an equal title to being called $(-1)^{\sqrt2}$. And there are infinitely many of them as a different choice of $n$ leads to a different number.

Comment: Yes, it is anumber. As you showed, it is a complex number.

Comment: A good choice is $\exp(i\pi r)$.  But one day you may learn about the "multi-valued" character of $a^b$ when $b$ is not an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would prefer not to consider $(-1)^r$ as definable in any sense. Because for me, $(-1)^{p/q}$ is $\bigl(\sqrt[q]{-1}\bigr)^p$ or $\sqrt[q]{(-1)^p}$, and I get:

- If $p,q$ are both odd, then both expressions are equal to $-1$, since $(-1)^q=-1$ therefore $\sqrt[q]{-1}=-1$.
- If $p$ is even, then both are clearly equal to $1$.
- If $q$ is even, then neither is well defined for me (it can be, but in a different way).

The problem here that the numbers $p/q$ with $q$ odd are dense in $\mathbb R_+$, therefore this exponential is quite badly discontinuous.

---

You can as well think that $(-1)^{p/q}$ is any (or all) of the roots of the polynomial $X^q=(-1)^p$, getting a similar thing as in the previous case, just with all the complex roots considered as well.

---

(All of these considerations strongly mimic the problem of $0^0$, which is considered to be $1$ by many people in combinatorics, however, we all know that it is not as simple as that.)

In the end, you can define $(-1)^r$ to be whatever you want, as long as you define it properly. However, as a reviewer of a paper, I would very likely reject such notation.

Comment: Really? You would **reject** the perfectly standard complex-analytic (multivalued) definition, $z^\alpha = \exp(\alpha \log z)$?

Comment: @mrf If used in the context where $(-1)$ happens to be 
"just one of the values you use it for", I would probably not. But defining solely $(-1)^r:=\exp(i\pi r)$ is nothing less and nothing more than an abuse of notation.